# How to get Facebook video info?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Basically, I want to get info from a Facebook video Id includes: title, id, download URL, thumbnail

For my code:

```
const response = await got(url);
const title = response.body
  .split('<title id="pageTitle">')[1]
  .split('</title>')[0];
const name = response.body
  .split('{__typename:"Page",name:"')
  .pop()
  .split('"')
  .shift();
const duration = response.body
  .split('playable_duration:')
  .pop()
  .split(',')
  .shift();

let thumbnail =
  'https:' +
  response.body
    .split('"thumbnailUrl":"https:')
    .pop()
    .split('"')
    .shift()
    .split('\\')
    .join('');
```

Currently, I using got module to **scrape** my Facebook URL, but sometimes I received a Facebook login screen.

Should I have use a Headless browser like puppeteer?

Can someone help me?

Comment: what have you tried so far? may you please add a [mcve] of those efforts to the question itself?

Comment: Edited for more details.

Comment: _“Should I have use a Headless browser like puppeteer?”_ - no, you _should have_ used their API, because Facebook does not allow you to scrape their frontend pages to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your reply! Can I use another way without Facebook API?